# Drag & Drop data from one Flex application to another. Possible?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I googled for quite some time now, but was not able to obtain a definite answer.
what we want to do in a Flex Web application is, for example, drag items from one DataGrid to a Flex app in a second window and drop the data there in another DataGrid.

Is this at all possible, for example by dragging a proxy image around and pass the actual data via using LocalConnection?

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: I'm going from memory here; but I think that you can drag from one app to another with AIR (on the desktop); but not in a browser.  Don't quote me on that.

Comment: Need it for FLex on the web unfortunately